# Would you consider Terracotta to be a mature product?

Tags: java, terracotta

I just don't know. I mean, there are a few topics that point me away from believing such.

For example, the latest stable version (3.0.0-stable), has a broken eclipse plugin that simply doesn't work at all. Furthermore, attempting to upgrade between revisions is an enormous hassle, as all servers are incompatible with all clients not of the exact same revision number.

I've yet to fully profile, but it seems like Terracotta could quickly become an easy bottleneck.

What are your thoughts, StackOverflow? Have you used Terracotta with success, or do you also find it a bit....immature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just an FYI,

The release you refer to - 3.0.0-stable0 - is the first milestone release of the 3.0 line.  This is the current, in progress version that has not yet been released.  The current stable release line is 2.7 (current version: 2.7.3).

If you are looking for a stable, mature product, you should base your opinions on 2.7.x, not 3.0.  The practice is quite commonplace to have a "bleeding edge" product and a stable release product.  It may be the terminology that has misled you.  For more information on release naming in use by Terracotta, please have a look at the [Buildology](http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/orgsite/Buildology) page.

Regarding version numbers, this is regrettable, but necessary.  In order for the product to improve, changes to the network protocol and underlying storage format happen from time to time.  When these changes occur, the product is incompatible with prior versions.  Rather than promise something that is not possible (backward compatibility) the Terracotta team has chosen instead to prohibit different versions from talking to one another.

In the 3.0 line forward, the notion of a Stable Terracotta API has been introduced, which will lay the groundwork for some amount of compatibility between dot releases, e.g. 3.0.0 -> 3.0.1.

HTH.

Regards,

Taylor Gautier
Product Manager, Terracotta

Comment: After working thoroughly with 2.7.3, I have high hopes for a successful implementation. It's DEFINITELY good to hear that minor revision changes will enable piecewise upgrading in the future, or this is at least planned and considered.

Thanks for the clarification and the depth of your response.